# Need help trying to combine multiple inc and php files with javascript and php mixed content

Tags: javascript, php

Im trying to use this script. Works well but what I need to combine are inc/php files in which I have a lot of  php openings and closures. Whenever the process reaches one of these if finishes.

```
<?php
$txt1 = file_get_contents('page-001.php');
$txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-002.php');
$fp = fopen('newcombined.php', 'w');
if(!$fp)
die('Could not create / open text file for writing.');
if(fwrite($fp, $txt1) === false)
die('Could not write to text file.');
echo 'Text files have been merged.'; 
?>
```

The content of page-001.php would be for example

```
<!--FW - DetectaDispositivo-->
<?php
content and functions mixing javascript and php
?>
```

The final result of my newcombined.php is:

```
<!--FW - DetectaDispositivo-->
```

I know a solution would be to replace php tags with echo, but thats supposed to be a bad use, and also, that will mean I will have to modify lots of files.

Thanks!

Comment: This process does not appear to be "compilation" in the commonly-understood sense used by programmers. PHP does not get compiled, in any case. I think what you're really doing is concatenating some files together into a single file. I've changed the tags to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Im concatenating files. I thought it as a compilation, because I will have different functions in different files, and I wanted them to be in just one file, but its a concatenation.

Comment: well "compiling" in more general usage can mean that (e.g. "I'm compiling a collection of poems"), but in programming terms it has another more specific meaning about translating source code into machine-language, and so it's not a good idea to use that term in the context of your question. I think it will be clearer for  people reading it, now I've edited.

Comment: Anyway I think the issue you're experiencing could occur if the page-001.php script is actually being _executed_, instead of simply fetching the raw text. `file_get_contents` can be used to run a HTTP request, if it interprets the string you give it as being (part of) a URL.

Comment: That would of course cause apache to execute the script, and what you get back would therefore not include any PHP source code, instead it would return the _result of executing that code_. And if that code only contains function definitions, and no actual immediate commands, then the result for that part of the file will be blank.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised if that's happening, because I'd have expected it to interpret the string as a local file path, and just read the file, but I can't think of a better explanation right now for what you're seeing.

Comment: All of these is been worked offline.
I have multiple files, with php and javascript mixed functions, and I want to make them 1 before uploading the files to the server.
So answering... no, page-001.php was not being executed.

Comment: SOLVED!
Its working
I corrected some of the inc files that had additional <?php ?>
Also I added a line on top to start my php file
 $txt1 = "<?php";

Thanks for the help

Comment: Great. If you solved it, please add a fuller description of your solution below, in the Answers section. You are allowed to answer your own question. That way other people will be more likely to benefit from your experience, as answered questions show up in search results more often, and people can then upvote your answer if it's useful to them (which in turn increases your reputation score).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$txt1 = "<?php";
$txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('GoogleTags.inc');
$txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('header.inc');
$txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('footer.inc');
$txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('site.inc');
$fp = fopen('destination-file.inc', 'w');
if(!$fp)
die('Could not create / open text file for writing.');
if(fwrite($fp, $txt1) === false)
die('Error en la compilación.');
echo 'Compilación exitosa.'; 
?>
```

I had some trouble inside one of the inc files that broke the code. But it was working before I noticed.